# Alexa custom slot is unidentified (Only for incorrect slot words)

Tags: javascript, alexa-skills-kit, alexa-slot

Slot values are: `campfire, city, beach`
and my utterance is: `{enviro} mood`

if i say: `campfire mood` -> everything works.
if i say: `peanuts mood` -> I don't get any value for that slot (see pic below)
[image]

Any idea what might be causing this? The skill is getting pretty big and I have other intents but none of them use this slot.

Answer (score 0):

As the skill is big the issue may be, there are other slots which may have many single words in it and Alexa is not able to map the right slot if no word is found. So, there are actually two ways to solve that issue :

First, try this - 
when you don't know what user might say then use `AMAZON.SearchQuery` slot.

Second Option - you should place all the moods which users might say in the slots.

Comment: Turns out skill was too big and alexa couldn't map it. I added more words and it works fine. it's now: Set mood to {enviro}